# Can someone explain why the signs of my coefficient estimates flip between a 1-way and 2-way fixed effects model? Also, loses significance?

Tags: r, interpretation, panel-data

I'm trying to measure the effect of the included IVs on an individual's self-esteem (binary:positive/negative). This is panel data across three waves. I am running an LPM FE model. I'm not sure I understand the 2WFE model entirely. So do the results I have come under the assumption that time and individual effects are removed? And so, my IVs have no effect (or negative) on an individual's self-esteem?

```
                         Dependent variable:             
             --------------------------------------------
                              POSITIVITY                 
                   1WFE (Year)               2WFE        
---------------------------------------------------------
INCOME              0.008***                -0.006       
                     (0.001)               (0.006)       
                                                         
HOMEOWN             0.028***                -0.023       
                     (0.003)               (0.025)       
                                                         
EDUC                0.003***                -0.019       
                     (0.001)               (0.033)       
                                                         
INSURANCE             0.015                 -0.011       
                     (0.011)               (0.029)       
                                                         
MARRIED              -0.001                 0.006        
                     (0.007)               (0.024)       
                                                         
PARENT              0.035***                0.013        
                     (0.009)               (0.052)       
                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------
Observations          4,942                 4,942        
R2                    0.010                 0.002        
Adjusted R2           0.008                 -1.999       
F Statistic  8.025*** (df = 6; 4933) 0.438 (df = 6; 1645)
=========================================================
Note:                         *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: Without some derails this will not be answerable!